# Why links to other SE questions appear to have been removed when question migrated?

Tags: support, status-completed, hyperlinks, migration

My [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149351/point-overplotting-on-maps-in-r-e-g-with-ggplot2-how-to-push-points-to-the) has just been migrated to GIS SE, but the links to some relevant questions (on SO) seem to have been removed automatically.

Is this the common procedure when it comes to links (on all SE sites)?

Comment: If you mean the post originating at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30288763/revisions, I cannot find any evidence that anything was lost.  I cannot even find any links to SO questions in the original. Are you perhaps referring to another question? If so, could you provide a link to it?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I was sure there were at least 2 questions in the "linked" section on the right when I last saw it on SO, but now that I've gone through the old version, I can't find anything either...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns alleged site behavior that cannot be confirmed or reproduced.

Comment: As long as I can't find any evidence for my words, I guess all I can do is agree to close the question. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: No apologies needed: we should view this as an effective and simple resolution of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are referring to is the Linked section at right of any sites (like Stack Overflow) using the new CSS.  Here that section is titled Related because we have not yet been upgraded to the new look.

[image]

What you are observing is the expected behaviour:

- When your question is hosted on Stack Overflow what you will see under Linked are Stack Overflow questions that may be related to it.
- When your question is hosted on GIS SE what you will see under Related are GIS SE questions that may be related to it.

There is a declined request on Meta SE to have the questions linked/related be drawn from all SE sites:

[Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar)

Comment: I suspected this might be what was referred to. @maj Note that if your question had links *within* it to other questions, those would still be there and pointed to the correct site. However it appears the questions you refer to linked to *your* question (unless some comments got dropped). I'm pretty sure those links will remain valid on that side even after migration, or go to a page indicating the post was migrated with the new address/link. As PolyGeo points out, the Linked and Related sections are per site and automatically generated/tracked. They're not actually part of your question.

Comment: @PolyGeo: You might be right. Just to have said this, I sort of *do* believe that there were 2 sections on the right - a larger one that contained all those roughly "related" questions (I don't remember the title exactly, but I also don't remember having agreed to try the beta) and one on top that contained only those 2 or 3 questions that I manually linked. Anyway, thanks for your ideas!

Comment: @maj the new CSS is not a beta - it is just filtering  down to us from the much larger sites being upgraded first